# Can multiple gene tonics stack in Bioshock 2?

Tags: bioshock-2

If I have a specific gene tonic in level 1 and level 2, is there any benefit to equipping both of them at the same time?  Will I get the full 1+2 bonuses? Or will I get just somewhat over the 2nd bonus?  Or is the level 1 tonic completely useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bonuses from the gene tonics stack, so if you equip a level 1 and a level 2 tonic, you will get the full bonuses from both.

Comment: mm.. It's actually bad news, 'cause it means I'd have more options to chose from, when deciding which tonics to use, and which to leave at the bank.
Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Source? How you have confirmed this?